# Webpack 5 Node Polyfill instructions don't work

Tags: webpack, jsforce

I am trying to install jsforce with:

webpack 5.17.0
webpack-cli 4.4.0

No matter what I do I get these errors:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/jsforce/lib/oauth2.js 8:18-40
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'querystring' in '/var/www/pos/node_modules/jsforce/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "querystring": require.resolve("querystring-es3") }'
    - install 'querystring-es3'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "querystring": false }
 @ ./node_modules/jsforce/lib/core.js 12:17-36
 @ ./node_modules/jsforce/lib/browser/jsforce.js 3:14-32
 @ ./src/modules/checkout.js 4:0-30
 @ ./src/index.js 3:0-45
```

(and so on with 3 other modules)

I have tried the requested steps:

- I have installed all 4 packages listed  (browserify-stream, util, browserify-timers, and querystring-es3)
- I have added the following to my webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
...
  resolve: {
    fallback: { 
        "querystring": require.resolve("querystring-es3"),
        "timers": require.resolve("timers-browserify"),
        "util": require.resolve("util/"),
        "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify")
    },
  },
...
```

And I restarted webpack.  Again, and again.  No change.

I have also tried this instead from a different blog post:

```
  resolve: {
    alias: { 
        stream: "stream-browserify",
        querystring: "querystring-es3",
        timers: 'timers-browserify',
        util: 'util'
    }
  },
```

Also makes absolutely no difference.

In short - none of the instructions provided actually do anything.  I've done all the steps exactly as stated and I continue to get the same error with the same instructions.  How is one supposed to get this module installed?

Here is my whole webpack config:

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    alias: { 
        stream: "stream-browserify",
        querystring: "querystring-es3",
        timers: 'timers-browserify',
        util: 'util'
    }
  },
  mode: 'development',
  experiments: {
    topLevelAwait: true,
  },
  watch: true,
  module: {
    rules: [
            {
                test: /\.s?[ac]ss$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    { loader: 'css-loader', options: { url: false, sourceMap: true } },
                    { loader: 'sass-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } }
                ],
            },{
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: [{
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].[ext]',
              outputPath: 'font/'
            }
        }]
      }
    ]
  },
  
    devtool: 'source-map',
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "style.css"
        })
        
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            vue: 'vue/dist/vue.js'
        },
    },
};
```

and my whole package.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "latest-version": "^5.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^4.2.0",
    "sass": "^1.32.5",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.1"
  },
  "name": "pos",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@stripe/terminal-js": "^0.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.0-beta1",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.3.0",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "jsforce": "^1.10.1",
    "less-loader": "^7.3.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.3.4",
    "querystring-es3": "^0.2.1",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "timers-browserify": "^2.0.12",
    "util": "^0.12.3",
    "vue": "^2.6.12",
    "webpack": "^5.17.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.4.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "private": true,
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```

I am including jsforce like this in my entry file:

```
import jsforce from 'jsforce';
```

Answer (score 4):

Ugh, of course, I had two overlapping resolve sections.